# scroll scrpit to particular button position to next id when click button

Tags: php, javascript, html

this is my jscript

```
 <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("button").on('click', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#button").offset().top
                }, 1000);


        });
    });
    </script>
```

this is my custom button

```
 <button name="button" style="margin: 9px 0 20px 0;padding: 3px 25px; background-color: red;color: white;font-weight: bold;" value="OK" type="button" >HAVE A QUESTIONS</button>
```

and this is scroll bottom location (to scroll top button to this location)

```
<!-- Have Question -->
<div class="content-teaser container text-center">
    <h3 class="text-red center-block text-center"  id="button" >Have Questions?</h3>
    <p>Talk with someone on the team We're here
to answer question</p>
```

all is work well but console put this error

TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

what is this error i can't understand plz solved this error because this error conflict to other script and my page doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this jQuery error..............

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("button").on('click', function(event) {

            var target = $("#button");

            if( target.length ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }

        });
    });
    </script>
```

in this way ADD TO CART button work & all jQuery work properly on this page

Answer (score 0):

You should place the whole function/script inside a so called IIFE like this:

```
(function($){

    //your code

})(jQuery);
```

In Wordpress the $ isn't attached to jQuery by default due to possible conflicts with other JavaScript libraries.

Comment: also put this error ---> TypeError: jQuery(...).offset(...) is undefined @Schurik

Comment: <script>
 (function($){
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $("button").on('click', function(event) {
        
     event.preventDefault();
         $('html, body').stop().animate({
             scrollTop: jQuery("#button").offset().top
         }, 1000);
     

 });
});
})(jQuery);
</script>

Comment: any other solution 4 this error